# Cant access method in main class

Tags: java

I'm new into java programming, so I'm now struggling with exceptions. So I would like to hear some advice from experienced users. My main question is why can't I user method "validate" in UserDemo class?

[My user class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9neh.jpg)

[Service where I check if first and last name is not longer than 15 and less than 3+throw exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ny2u.jpg)

[User class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNVUB.jpg)

[Demo class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjTeC.jpg)

Comment: I see you're new here. Please use code block formatting and try to refrain from posting pictures of code. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Hi, `validate` is defined in `UserValidationService` so `user.validate(user)` won't work - instead you would need to do `UserValidationService uvs = new UserValidationService(); uvs.validate(user);`

Comment: Don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)). Use [edit] option to correct your post.

Comment: Don't use link here, paste the complete code and ask where is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, you're trying to call the method `validate` as if it belongs to the `User` class, because you call `user.validate(...)`. However, your `UserValidationService` contains the `validate` method which accepts a `User` as a parameter. So in your main class you'll need to instantiate the service and pass the user to it:

```java
UserValidationService service = new UserValidationService();
service.validate(user);
```